# Why was the hair of Howl colored black when he was young?

Tags: howls-moving-castle

In the beginning-middle of the movie, Sophie accidentally made Howl paint his hair black instead of his [natural blonde color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkwdU.jpg). I also suspect that this is his natural color because he felt so upset after the incident.

But if this is right, then why does Sophie see him in [the vision](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/howlscastle/images/8/85/Howl10.png/revision/latest?cb=20120129220726) in his current color (black) which he got years after that scenario?

Was that an accident in script? Or is there another meaning for that part of the story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sophie went and organized his hair coloring products (like he said not to) Howl's hair is naturally *black* he dyes his hair blonde. When he rushed out of the bathroom this hair was a bright orange because his products weren't in the order he was used to, so by instinct he chose the wrong bottle. When he got depressed because he wasn't "beautiful" his hair turned into it's natural black color.
Because his hair is naturally black, in the vision she saw, his hair is black, not blonde.